# Running into connect exception learning D4Lj examples

Tags: deep-learning

Can you please help me understand why I am running into this issue...

14:22:15.752 [main] INFO org.deeplearning4j.base.MnistFetcher - Downloading MNIST...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:540)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1181)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1075)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1009)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2758)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2680)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1843)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1117)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1460)
    at org.deeplearning4j.base.MnistFetcher.tryDownloadingAFewTimes(MnistFetcher.java:184)
    at org.deeplearning4j.base.MnistFetcher.tryDownloadingAFewTimes(MnistFetcher.java:177)
    at org.deeplearning4j.base.MnistFetcher.downloadAndUntar(MnistFetcher.java:156)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.fetchers.MnistDataFetcher.(MnistDataFetcher.java:67)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.MnistDataSetIterator.(MnistDataSetIterator.java:67)
    at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.MnistDataSetIterator.(MnistDataSetIterator.java:53)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to the latest version. The mnist binaries were moved to a new location. That or your place you are running the fetcher is not able to connect remotely to the server (hence connection refused)

Comment: Thanks ..I downloaded the MNIST files locally and it worked. The Connection refused threw me off...